# HTML5 tags and WAI ARIA

Tags: html, wai-aria

A quick question, if I'm using within my markups 'main' am I still obligated to use 'role' attribute?

For example, should I use:

```
<main>
```

or

```
<main role="main">
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`main` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/grouping-content.html#the-main-element) has the [`main` role](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/dom.html#index-aria-main) by default.

You are allowed to explicitly set the `role` attribute with this value, but it’s [not recommended](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/dom.html#aria-usage-note):

> In the majority of cases setting an ARIA `role` and/or `aria-*` attribute that matches the default implicit ARIA semantics is unnecessary and not recommended as these properties are already set by the browser.

However, user agents that don’t support HTML5 (but WAI-ARIA) might benefit from this attribute.

Comment: So *currently* I'd say it's *better* (doesn't hurt any, might help some) to implement the `role` attribute.